# Converting digitized shapefile into network in ArcGIS Pro - Standalone user-defined junction is detected

Tags: arcgis-pro, network-analyst, standalone

I am new to ArcGIS. I will briefly present my use case.

I have an historical map of a railroad network in Italy. I have georeferenced the map and digitized it accordingly. I have now 2 shapefiles, one for the rail (polyline feature), one for the cities (point feature) touched by the rail. In particular, the way I digitized the railroad is the following: each entry in the rail shapefile is the portion of the railroad connecting two successive cities, and the cities should work as junctions of the different portions of the rail connecting each couple of cities. Important: when digitizing, I made sure the snapping tool was active, so that each rail portion connects to a couple of cities. I report a picture of a toy example with 4 cities (point features) and 3 rail portions (polyline features). By clicking on each point, it shows that each point connects to the rail portions as expected.

[image]

Now, I would like to convert my point and polyline shapefiles into a network dataset, to perform origin-destination analysis along the rail, using the point features as origins and destinations. Then, I create a network dataset using both my shapefiles as sources. When I build it, I receive the error message "Standalone user-defined junction is detected" for the cities shapefile, ObjectID 1 and 2 (but not 3 and 4!). Apparently, for some reason that I don't understand, ArcGIs does not understand that that the first 2 cities are connected through the first 2 rail portions, but it does understand that the last 2 cities are connected through the last portion. Indeed, using the explore network functionality, if I click on the last rail portion, it is recognized as a network, but nothing happens if I click on the first 2 rail portions.

[image]

Am I missing something?